# Using DSL router for hub only

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dsl-modem, hub

Is there a way to use my ATT DSL router as a hub/switch only? I'm cancelling my DSL service but need a 4 port hub. When I disconnect DSL service, the other ports don't work.  I have a Netgear b90-755025.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable DHCP on your router and set a the router's IP outside the DHCP range of your other router, it usually works as a makeshift switch.

You'll need to dig around on your router's settings pages for these options. Only use the LAN ports on the router. Do not use the WAN port; it will not work.

There may be some issues as the other router on your LAN may get angry if it sees other router-only packets coming from inside "its" LAN. Even though you disabled DHCP, there are other router services that are still running that will send out discovery packets. These can be problematic on more temperamental routers.